# 2-dimensional array in a struct in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, c99, flexible-array-member

I'm trying to initialize a 2-dimensional array in a structure but I always get an error :

```
gcc -g -Wall -W -I/usr/include/SDL   -c -o fractal.o fractal.c
In file included from fractal.c:2:0:
fractal.h:12:12: error: array type has incomplete element type ‘double[]’
     double values[][];
```

Here's the code:

```
struct fractal {

    char name[64];
    int height;
    int width;
    double a;
    double b;
    double meanValue;       
    double values[][];  /*This line is causing the error*/
 };
```

Ideally I'd like to initialize the height and width of the 2-dimensional array like this:

```
struct fractal {

    /*... Same code as above ...*/      

    double values[width][height];  
 };
```

But then I get two other errors when compiling:

```
gcc -g -Wall -W -I/usr/include/SDL   -c -o fractal.o fractal.c
In file included from fractal.c:2:0:
fractal.h:12:19: error: ‘width’ undeclared here (not in a function)
     double values[width][height];
                   ^
fractal.h:12:26: error: ‘height’ undeclared here (not in a function)
     double values[width][height];
                          ^
```

I've looked about everywhere but my code should work and I can't figure out why it doesn't.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Arrays can not be declared without a size (except in one very narrow case which you can't use if you insist on arrays of arrays), or with structure members (especially uninitialized) when inside the structure itself. Either resort to using a single one-dimensional array for your "2d" array and emulate the "2d" part, or use pointers and dynamic allocation.

Comment: And what if I want to initialize the whole array with '0' and and know the overall size(width and height)?

Comment: @Rodesc: there are certainly solutions to your real problem... but this way is definitely a dead end. Maybe you could  give some more context on what you are trying to achive.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Not a dead end if you abuse the effective type rule a bit and force pointer conversions from `double[]` to an array pointer, as demonstrated in my answer. Bit tricky but well-defined and portable.

Comment: If you not define exact size of array, how you expect the compiler will know the size of structure? Use `double *` or `double **` and allocate the array dynamically.

Comment: @Lundin OK, but I think sometimes the better answer to this question is 'Why did you think you needed flexible array members, and isn't there a better way?' I feel there usually is, and answering the question literally is not always the biggest favour to the OP.

Comment: @Lundin: the dead end is a dynamic array of incomplete type. And correctly using flexible members is tricky for beginners. Without more context, I am not sure  that this is the best way for the real problem

Comment: @underscore_d It is a fairly common problem though, for example when writing some form of file header followed by a 2D array, like for example the bitmap picture format.

Comment: @Lundin But that, to me, often indicates a bad design: expecting that structures in memory to map 1:1 to a defined file format is usually nonportable at best, and the proper solution is normally to write careful de/serialising code that writes the bytes needed, rather than hoping the compiler will lay a structure out the right way over it. I've been there and tried to do this, and it even worked, but then further reading about what little the language guaranteed made my realise my code was actually UB & just *happened* to work exactly per my expectations. Expectations can be a dangerous thing!

Comment: @underscore_d The structure itself may not map 1:1 to raw binary, but that's a separate problem with all structures. The flexible array member part in itself is however guaranteed to be contiguous and aligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a disclaimer, this is something of an advanced topic, so if you are a beginner you might want to just back away from it entirely and just use a `double*` array followed by a call to malloc for each pointer. (Fine for beginners, unacceptable in professional code.)

It is an advanced topic since this particular case is a weakness in C. The feature you are trying to use, with an empty array at the end of a struct, is known as *flexible array member*. This only works for one dimension however. If both dimensions are unknown at compile time, you have to come up with a work-around.

The allocation part is as for any flexible array member: allocate the struct dynamically and make size for the trailing array.

```
fractal_t* f = malloc(sizeof *f + sizeof(double[height][width]) );
```

(In this case taking advantage of the convenient VLA syntax, although a flexible array member is not a VLA.)

Technically, the last member of the struct is supposedly `double[]` now, or so says the struct declaration. But memory returned by malloc has no actual *effective type* until you access it, after which the effective type of that memory becomes the type used for the access.

We can use this rule to access that memory as if it was a `double[][]`, even though the pointer type in the struct is a different one. Given a fractal `f`, the code for accessing through a pointer becomes something like this:

```
double (*array_2D)[width] = (double(*)[width]) f->values;
```

Where `array_2D` is an array pointer. The most correct type to use here would have been an array pointer to an array of double, `double (*)[height][width]`, but that one comes with mandatory ugly accessing `(*array_2D)[i][j]`. To avoid such ugliness, a common trick is to leave out the left-most dimension in the array pointer declaration, then we can access it as `array_2D[i][j]` which looks far prettier.

Example code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct 
{
  char name[64];
  size_t height;
  size_t width;
  double a;
  double b;
  double meanValue;       
  double values[];
} fractal_t;


fractal_t* fractal_create (size_t height, size_t width)
{
  // using calloc since it conveniently fills everything with zeroes
  fractal_t* f = calloc(1, sizeof *f + sizeof(double[height][width]) );
  f->height = height;
  f->width = width;
  // ...
  return f;
}

void fractal_destroy (fractal_t* f)
{
  free(f);
}

void fractal_fill (fractal_t* f)
{
  double (*array_2D)[f->width] = (double(*)[f->width]) f->values;

  for(size_t height=0; height < f->height; height++)
  {
    for(size_t width=0; width < f->width; width++)
    {
      array_2D[height][width] = (double)width; // whatever value that makes sense
    }
  }
}

void fractal_print (const fractal_t* f)
{
  double (*array_2D)[f->width] = (double(*)[f->width]) f->values;

  for(size_t height=0; height < f->height; height++)
  {
    for(size_t width=0; width < f->width; width++)
    {
      printf("%.5f ", array_2D[height][width]); 
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main (void)
{
  int h = 3;
  int w = 4;

  fractal_t* fractal = fractal_create(h, w);
  fractal_fill(fractal); // fill with some garbage value
  fractal_print(fractal);
  fractal_destroy(fractal);
}
```

Comment: That is indeed an advanced solution... Among the pitfalls, `struct fractal_t f;` gives a flexible member of size 0, and you cannot use arrays of that kind of struct. In addition `sizeof(struct fractal_t)` gives the size for an empty flexible member. That being said, it is the idiomatic way and is commonly used. +1

Comment: @SergeBallesta That same problem exists for all flexible array members, they don't make any sense unless you either allocate dynamically, or someone else has done the allocation (like when reading a binary file). Ideally I suppose the above solution should be made an "ADT" with opaque pointers, so that that no instance can be created directly by the caller.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort into your answer, didn't know it was such a complicated matter. Much clearer now :)

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic dimensions arrays is not the point where C is at its best... Simple Variable Length Arrays were only introduced in the language in the C99 version and were made optional in C11 version. They are still not accepted in MSVC 2017...

But here, you are trying to set one in a struct. That is not supported at all because a struct must have a constant size<sup>(*)</sup> (how could be handled arrays of structs). So I am sorry but this code *should not work* and I know no way to express that in C language.

A common way would be to replace the 2D dynamic array with a pointer, allocate the pointer to a 2D array and then use it, but even this is not really simple.

You have to design your struct differently...

---

<sup>(*)</sup> The last element of a struct may be of an incomplete type, for example `int tab[];`. That is a dangerous feature because the programmer is responsable for providing room for it. But anyway you cannot build an array of incomplete types.

Comment: MSVC 2017 still struggles with C90 compliance, so that's no wonder. And there is nothing dangerous with using a flexible array member - it was only dangerous pre-C99 when people used "the struct hack", which was indeed dangerous. If you are stuck with MSVC 2017 from 1989, then you might not be able to write such code, as flexible array members were introduced in 1999 and I'm not sure if MS has yet managed to update MSVC 2017 to the year 1999 standard. They are certainly not compliant to C99.

Comment: @Lundin: they are indeed C11 compliant on this part. As I said VLA are explicitely an optional feature in C11. And storing a VLA array of VLA arrays in a struct is certainly a bad idea...

Comment: I would bet my shoes that they are not C11 compliant in the slightest. You can easily test it, knowing that they do not support VLA: `#ifndef __STDC_VERSION__
#error TRASH COMPILER
#endif
#if __STDC_VERSION__ < 201100L
#error 1990s compiler
#elif defined __STDC_NO_VLA__
#error OMG MS did something right
#else
#error TRASH COMPILER
#endif` (Don't run this on a compiler that does support VLA)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem while designing a struct to hold both the domain values (N x 1 vector) and the solution values (N x M matrix) in my ODE solver, so as to simplify the function interfaces. N and M are simulation-dependent and hence are unknown a priori. I solved it by using [GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/vectors.html)'s vector-matrix module. I found it more streamlined to work with than casting a FAM (albeit allocated as 2D) to a standalone whole-array-pointer.

After allocating memory for the struct, all we need to do is invoke `gsl_matrix_alloc()` to reserve space for the matrix. After we are done, calling `gsl_matrix_free()` will destroy it. Please note that these functions are data-type dependent as explained in the documentation.

**Filename:**  **`struct_mat.c`**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_statistics.h>

typedef struct _fractal {
    char name[64];
    size_t height;
    size_t width;
    double a;
    double b;
    double meanValue;
    gsl_matrix *values;
 } fractal;

fractal * fractal_create(size_t height, size_t width) {
    fractal * fractalObj = (fractal *) malloc(sizeof(fractal));
    fractalObj -> values = gsl_matrix_alloc(height, width);

    if (fractalObj == NULL || fractalObj -> values == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "NULL pointer returned while allocating fractal object.. Exiting program.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fractalObj -> height = height;
    fractalObj -> width = width;
    fractalObj -> meanValue = 0.0;

    return fractalObj;
}

void fractal_populate(fractal * fractalObj) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    double current_value = 0.0;

    for (size_t r = 0; r < fractalObj -> height; ++r) {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < fractalObj -> width; ++c) {
            current_value = (double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
            gsl_matrix_set(fractalObj -> values, r, c, current_value);
        }
    }
}

void fractal_calcMeanValue(fractal * fractalObj) {

    gsl_vector_view colVec;

    for (size_t col = 0; col < fractalObj -> values -> size2; ++col) {
        colVec = gsl_matrix_column(fractalObj -> values, col);
        fractalObj -> meanValue += gsl_stats_mean(colVec.vector.data, colVec.vector.stride, colVec.vector.size);
    }

    fractalObj -> meanValue /= fractalObj -> values -> size2;

    printf("\nThe mean value of the entire matrix is %lf\n", fractalObj -> meanValue);

}

void fractal_display(fractal * fractalObj) {
    printf("\n");
    for (size_t r = 0; r < fractalObj -> height; ++r) {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < fractalObj -> width; ++c) {
            printf("%lf ", gsl_matrix_get(fractalObj -> values, r, c));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void fractal_delete(fractal * fractalObj) {
    gsl_matrix_free(fractalObj -> values);
    free(fractalObj);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    // Program takes number of rows and columns as command line parameters
    switch(argc) {
        case 3:
            printf("Running program..\n"); // to avoid the declaration-succeeding-label error

            size_t height = atoi(argv[1]);
            size_t width = atoi(argv[2]);

            fractal * myFractal = fractal_create(height, width);

            fractal_populate(myFractal);
            fractal_display(myFractal);
            fractal_calcMeanValue(myFractal);

            fractal_delete(myFractal);
            return 0;

        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: struct_mat <rows> <columns>\n");
            return 1;
    }

}
```

Compile by linking with the GSL and GSL CBLAS libraries:

```
gcc -std=c99 struct_mat.c -o struct_mat -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

You may install [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) via your distribution's [package manager](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=GSL), Cygwin on Windows or by compiling the [source](http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gsl/).

In my limited experience, using a standard data structure proves to be far easier than wrestling with either FAMs or array-of-pointers-to-1D-arrays. However, the caveat is that we have to remember allocating memory for the matrix after allocating the struct itself.